# In aggregate: sum not meaningful for factors

Tags: r, aggregate, factors

I am trying something that should be simple, any hint on what is going on is very welcomed.

I have a large data frame with country imports from some municipalities. For some countries I have 2 entries. I want to sum the imports from each municipality and having a unique row for each country. I am using the `aggregate` function. For example (I include a small part of the data frame):

```
municipalities<-c("country",1100056, 1100106,1100205,1100304,1200104,1200252)
c1<-c("Afghanistan",2,34,23.4,5,0,0)    
c2<-c("Afghanistan",0,20,11.1,5.4,2,0)    
c3<-c("Albania",12,120,11.4,5.1,12,10)    
c4<-c("Albania",0,40,61.1,65.4,652,2)
df<-as.data.frame(rbind(municipalities,c1,c2,c3,c4))
```

Basically I am trying

```
df<-df[-1,]    
aggregate(df[,2:7],list(df[,1]),sum)
```

but I receive a message:

```
Error in Summary.factor(c(4L, 1L), na.rm = FALSE) : 
  sum not meaningful for factors
```

I have tried to force the `df` to be numeric, declared the characters as characters etc. but nothing seems to help.

Comment: How are you creating your actual data.frame? The way you have given in the example is creating `factors` which can't be summed. Consider giving sample from your actual data. you can perhaps paste output of  `dput(head(df))` in the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because of how you're creating your dataframe. For example, `c1` is character because a vector can only have one class. When you put them into a dataframe, those character vectors are further coerced to factor. Thus you're trying to run `sum` on factors. You figured this out already, but then tried to convert factors to numeric, which is probably giving you nonsensical results.

The easy answer is to build your dataframe column-wise rather than row-wise, so you don't get into so many coercion problems.

Given the data you already have, this will solve your problem:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x)))
aggregate(. ~ V1, df, sum)
```

(Thanks to @AnandaMahto for the much cleaner way of doing that conversion than what I originally had.)

Result:

```
           V1 V2  V3   V4   V5  V6 V7
1 Afghanistan  2  54 34.5 10.4   2  0
2     Albania 12 160 72.5 70.5 664 12
```

Comment: Try: `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x)))` (where `df` is from the step "`df <- df[-1, ]`" in the original question. A bit cleaner than what you propose.

Comment: Oh, and for the `aggregate` step, try `aggregate(. ~ V1, df2, sum)`.

Comment: @Thomas - What if the data set is large and `lapply()` is slow on it?

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil having `factor`s where you want `numeric` is a problem that should be solved upstream. This answer shows a quick fix, but if you have a large data set that is being slow you should fix it at the time you read in the data.