# What does "df[] <-" do in R

Tags: r, variables, dataframe

Pretty simple question, and I have had a quick search in google and stackoverflow.
I found this in another post: [In aggregate: sum not meaningful for factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19493252/in-aggregate-sum-not-meaningful-for-factors).

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x)))
```

how does `df[]` work?

Comment: Succinctly, `df <-` creates a new object, `df[] <- ` modifies an existing object.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It invokes `[<-.data.frame` (i.e., the data.frame method for `[<-`). That way you assign a list to a data.frame. You could also do

```
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x))))
```

Example:

```
DF <- data.frame(a=1:2, b=3:4)
DF[] <- list(c=10:11, d=12:13)
#    a  b
# 1 10 12
# 2 11 13
```

But compare with this:

```
DF <- `[<-.data.frame`(DF, , , list(c=c("a", "b"), d=c("d", "e")))
#   c d
# 1 a d
# 2 b e
```

VS. this:

```
DF <- `[<-.data.frame`(DF, 1:2, 1:2, list(c=c("a", "b"), d=c("d", "e")))
#  a b
#1 a d
#2 b e
```

There is also this:

```
DF <- as.data.frame(list(c=10:11, d=12:13))
#    c  d
# 1 10 12
# 2 11 13
```

Comment: That idiom is also used with matrices, e.g. `m <- matrix(1,5,5)`, and then compare `m[] <- 5` with `m <- 5`.

Comment: Thanks for the speeedygonzalez reply!

Answer (score 12):

To add to what Roland wrote,{edit} **aaagh he ninja'd me w/ his comment** the point is that using `DF[]` retains the existing object `DF` with its attributes, in this case the fact that it's got two dimensions and the names `a` and `b` .

```
Rgames> foo<- matrix(1:6,2,3)
Rgames> foo[]<-7:12
Rgames> foo
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    7    9   11
[2,]    8   10   12
Rgames> foo<-7:12
Rgames> foo
[1]  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

Comment: +1 for the info that it "retains the existing object 'DF' with its attributes" spelled out.