# How to shuffle data frame entries in R

Tags: r, dataframe, random, shuffle, sample

I have a data frame with dimension 24,523x3,468 and I want to shuffle the entries of this dataframe. For example, I have a simple data frame

```
df <- data.frame(c1=c(1, 1.5, 2, 4), c2=c(1.1, 1.6, 3, 3.2), c3=c(2.1, 2.4, 1.4, 1.7)) 
df_shuffled = transform(df, c2 = sample(c2))
```

It works for one column, but I want to shuffle all column, or all rows. I tried

```
col = colnames(df)
for (i in 1:ncol(df)){
  df2 = transform(df, col[i] = sample(col[i]))
}
df2
```

It will produce an error like this

[image: error]

I have tried this too to shuffle, but it only shuffles rows and columns

```
df_shuf = df[sample(rownames(df), nrow(df)), sample(colnames(df), ncol(df))]
df_shuf
```

[image: shuffle]

How can I shuffle the entries of the data frame df using a loop for I by rows and columns?

Comment: To get a good answer to this question you need to explain exactly what you mean by 'shuffling' the data frame.

Comment: @GeorgeSavva randomly swapping the entries by rows and columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I find the `lapply(df, sample)` method the most straight-forward (and canonical), a literal fix to your `for` loop is to recognize that `transform` cannot use `col[i]` on the LHS of an assignment. You can instead use `df2[[ col[i] ]]`:

```r
df2 <- df
col = colnames(df)
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  df2[[ col[i] ]] = sample(df2[[ col[i] ]])
}
```

We don't really need the names, though, you can indices instead:

```r
df2 <- df
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  df2[[ i ]] = sample(df2[[ i ]])
}
```

---

This assumes, of course, that you intend to discard the correlation between values in a row. For instance, the minimum value for columns `c1` and `c2` occur together in row 1; after sampling, however, they may occur in different rows.

If your intent is to keep each row together, then we would just need to sample the rows, preserving the "observation" quality of the frame:

```r
df2 <- df[sample(nrow(df)),]
```

Answer (score 5):

One way to solve your problem:

```
df[] = lapply(df, sample)
```

Comment: can you explain the `df[]` syntax?  why does this lead to `df` being a data frame and not a list?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165588/what-does-df-do-in-r

Comment: To paraphrase a comment there, *"Succinctly, `df <-` creates a new object, `df[] <-` modifies **the contents of** an existing object"*. In this case, `df <-` becomes a list with the desired values but it is not a frame; `df[] <-` replaces the contents but preserves the fact that it is a `data.frame`. It could just as easily be `df <- data.frame(lapply(df, sample))`, but the answer is more succinct (and fewer operations).