# Error in Summary.factor(1L, na.rm = FALSE) : sum not meaningful for factors for aggregate

Tags: r, aggregate

I have similar questiln as [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19493252/in-aggregate-sum-not-meaningful-for-factors)

```
value <- 1:10
Name <- c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5))
data <- data.frame(Name, value)
```

My approach using aggregate is

```
> aggregate(factor(Name) ~ value, data=data, FUN="sum")
Error in Summary.factor(1L, na.rm = FALSE) : 
  sum not meaningful for factors
```

And i follow the link while have the same error

```
> data[] <- lapply(data, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x)))
> aggregate(Name ~ value, data, sum)
Error in Summary.factor(1L, na.rm = FALSE) : 
  sum not meaningful for factors
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `aggregate(value ~ factor(Name), data=data, FUN="sum")`. you can't sum factors. The error message is pretty straight forward

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to switch `Name` and `value`:

```
aggregate(value ~ Name, data = data, FUN = "sum")
  Name value
1    A    15
2    B    40
```

Comment: thanks @Sven Hohenstein Sorry for the stupid mistake.