# R - Aggregate and wrong sum value

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm encountering a problem while processing some data.

I have a dataframe which is as follow :

```
Chrom Avg_Coverage

1000568 21.88194
1000568 1.25642
1000568 1.22052
1000568 1.04954
1000568 0.81894
1000568 0.12160
1000568 0.00000
1000568 0.00000
1000568 0.00000
```

I'm trying to get the `Avg_Coverage` sum of all those values that are the same, so I use the following code to do this :

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x)))
df_result=aggregate(. ~Chrom, df, sum)
```

(from [In aggregate: sum not meaningful for factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19493252/in-aggregate-sum-not-meaningful-for-factors), since my datas are factors)

No errors, but the results is not correct, see :

```
Chrom Avg_Coverage
1000568 10400
```

What did I do wrong, and how could I fix this?

I'm more of a biologist than an programmer.

Comment: `factor`s don't sum well, but neither do `character`s. I would suggest leaving your grouping variable as a factor, and converting only your `Avg_Coverage` column to a numeric. `df$Avg_Coverage = as.numeric(as.character(df$Avg_Coverage))` should do it.

Comment: Instead of fixing it _now_, fix it when the data.frame is being created -- why is `Avg_Coverage` a factor, when it should be numeric?

Answer (score 0):

First, check what type of data are in your data.frame:

```
str(df)
```

It doesn't matter what `Chrom` is, but you want `Avg_Coverage` to be numeric (or double).  If `str` reports that `Avg_Coverage` is a factor, then convert it to numeric with this code

```
df$Avg_Coverage <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Avg_Coverage))
```

Then get your aggregate sums:

```
aggregate(Avg_Coverage ~ Chrom, df, sum)
```